# Having Issue on Adding Content After Div

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at this snippet and let me know why I am not able to add content after div

```css
div{background:yellow; height:200px; width:200px;}
div:after {
  content: "Content";
}
```

```html
<div>
  hi
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the confusion? I see the div you added and then the pseudo element that hold the text "Content"!

Comment: Why content is not showing AFTER div?

Comment: :after does not mean that "Content" will show under the yellow box.

Comment: so if I want to do that? How can I do it?

Comment: By after you mean inline?

Comment: One way is to add margin-top and display: block;

Comment: Yeas I actually would like to create a button like div which enable to click and slide the box

Comment: "::after" inserts after the *content* of an element, not after the element itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo mean something like this?

```css
div{
  background:yellow; 
  height:200px; 
  width:200px;
  
  position: relative;
}
#div1:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "Content";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  
  background: #F1F2F3;
}

#div2:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "Content";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  top: 100%;
  
  background: #F1F2F3;
}
```

```html
<div id='div1'>
  hi
</div>

<br/>

<div id='div2'>
  hi2
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still achieve the effect that you seem to be looking for, you would just need a bit more css to actually position the new information where you want it visually.

```
div{background:yellow; height:200px; width:200px; position:relative}
div:after {
  content: "Content";
  position:absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
}
```

However, I would agree with @Jonathan, that separate markup would be far clearer, especially if you plan on interactivity like a button.

Answer (score 0):

"::after" inserts after the content of an element, not after the element itself.

You need to create another element to hold the comment

```css
div{background:yellow; height:200px; width:200px;}
div.holder::after {
  content: "Content";
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
<div>
  hi
</div>
</div>
```

or: https://jsfiddle.net/tg5v5v5y/